# Extracting an ArrayList of names minus the first name

Tags: java, arrays

Reading in a list of strings like

```
Bob,Jim,Greg
Bob,Allison,Jamie,Craig 
Bob,Tim,Allen
```

How would I get an ArrayList with

```
Jim Greg as the first element
Allison Jamie Craig as the second element 
Tim Allen as the third element
```

Comment: I know I have to use .split(","), but other than that I am a little lost

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that you want to split on \n character.

Comment: Is that 3 separate strings? Or is that 1 string with newlines appended to the lines?

Comment: Those are 3 separate strings.

Comment: are you getting those strings in an array/arraylist ?

Comment: Nope, I am reading them in via BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(stringLinks.size());
String line;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] names = line.split(",")
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(names[1]);
    for(int i = 2; i < names.length; i++) {
        tmp.append(" ").append(name);
    }
    list.add(tmp.toString());
}
```

Comment: In your for loop you need to start i from 1 and not from 2, as we just need to skip the first String

Comment: I start from `1`, see `new StringBuilder(names[1]);`

Comment: oops just saw that..sorry  about that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above strings are separate and are available in some sort of a colection (I am assuming an Array) you just need to do a split on comma character and then append the remaining part. (This is a very simple technique, however you can use regex to extract more complexy structures).

```
public List extractNames(String[] nameArr)
{
     List<Steing> nameList = new ArrayList<String>():
     for(String str : nameArr)
     {
         String[] tokens = name.split(",");
         String name = "";
         for(int i = 1 ; i < tokens.length ; ++i)
         {
               name += tokens[i];
         }
         nameList.add(name);
     }
  return nameList;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `name += name`, it should be `name += " " + tokens[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList = x; // initializated before.
for (int i=x.size(); i==0; i--){
   if(i!=0){
      // extract the elements of x and store in another arraylist
   }
   // if i==0 simple do nothing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = null; 
StringTokenizer tizer = null;
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line = in.readLine())!=null)
{
    tizer = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
    tizer.nextToken(); //Get rid of Bob
    String tempStr = "";
    while(tizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        tempStr = tempStr + tizer.nextToken() + " "; //Get the rest of the names per line
    }
    nameList.add(tempStr.trim());
}
```